# Unable to install ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 7 in my Toshiba Satellite pro L510

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

I have burned the iso to a dvd. But while trying to install it is coming till the option of install ubuntu alongside Windows. But after that it is asking me to remove the dvd from the drive and directly going to boot window. Anybody can help me please?